# php curl авторизация на сайте с другого IP

Tags: php, curl, cookie, guzzle

Думаю реализовать такой скриптик: 
Авторизуюсь у себя в браузере
Сохраняю строку с cookie и передаю ее в скрипт на сервере

Можно ли обойти защиту при использовании cookie с другого ip?

```
    public function upload($cookie)
    {
        $url = 'https://exmo.com/ru/wallet';

        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
            'headers' => [
                'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36',
                'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
                'Cookie' => $cookie,
            ],
        ]);
        echo $response->getBody();
    }
```

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $your_proxy); добавили?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin естественно)

Comment: А какую ошибку скрипт отдает?

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов не наблюдаю ошибок нигде. Просто в браузере отображается не авторизированная страничка.